# Cómo reemplazar con str_replace() si tengo un array con valores contenidos en otros

Tags: php, str-replace

Estoy intentando reemplazar un versículo bíblico que se encuentra dentro de una variable con mucho texto, por un enlace hacía un buscador.

La cuestión es que el último dígito se queda fuera del reemplazo, y en lugar de tener un enlace como por ejemplo `Genesis 3:18`, obtengo un enlace con `Genesis 3:1`, dejando fuera el `8`, pero el texto del enlace sí está completo y se muestra `Genesis 3:18`, con el `8` como texto y `Genesis 3:1` como enlace.

Bien, uso el siguiente código:

```
foreach ($enlace as $valor) {
    $quest = '<a href="http://exegesis-biblica.com/search.php?search='.$valor.'">'.$valor.'</a>';
    $articulo =  str_replace($valor, $quest, $articulo);
}
```

La variable $enlace contiene:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Genesis 1:1
    [1] => Genesis 1:2
    [2] => Genesis 1:26
    [3] => Genesis 1:3
    [4] => Genesis 1:4
    [5] => Genesis 1:5
    [6] => Genesis 1:6
    [7] => Genesis 1:7
    [8] => Genesis 1:8
    [9] => Genesis 1:9
    [10] => Genesis 1:10
    [11] => Genesis 1:11
    [12] => Genesis 1:12
    [13] => Genesis 1:13
    [14] => Genesis 1:14
    [15] => Genesis 1:15
    [16] => Genesis 1:16
    [17] => Genesis 1:17
    [18] => Genesis 1:18
    [19] => Genesis 1:19
    [20] => Genesis 1:20
    [21] => Genesis 1:21
    [22] => Genesis 1:22
    [23] => Genesis 1:23
    [24] => Genesis 1:24
    [25] => Genesis 1:25
    [26] => Genesis 1:26
    [27] => Genesis 1:27
    [28] => Isaias 45:5
    [29] => Genesis 1:28
    [30] => Genesis 1:29
    [31] => Genesis 1:30
    [32] => Genesis 1:31
)
```

Comment: Muestra el código donde obtienes la variable `$enlace` y si es posible el resultado de un `print_r($enlace)`. Está pasando algo cuando el versículo tiene más de dos dígitos. Muestra también lo que envías a tu html como enlace, pues veo que tienes una variable `$articulo` con un replace... a ver si no estás quitando en alguna parte la última cifra.

Comment: Al hacer un ECHO en la variable $quest durante el bucle, el resultado es el esperado, me da los enlaces completos; pero al hacer str_replace() es cuando ocurre el problema y no hace bien el reemplazo.

Comment: La ultima cifra no se quita, aparece fuera del enlace como texto.

Comment: Creo que estás confundido, esa es la variable $book. De acuerdo a tu código la variable $enlace es un arreglo, array que obtienes en alguna parte, por eso la lees en un bucle foreach... ¿Puedes mostrar el código que hay antes del foreach ($enlance...)

Comment: Lo que se encuentra en la variable $articulo es volátil, sale de una consulta MySql y cambia dependiendo el articulo a mostrar. La variable enlace sale del preg_match_all($book, $articulo, $enlace); La variable $book es solo el patrón a buscar en la variable $articulo, y pertenece al código justo antes del foreach($enlace).

Comment: Si como dices: "Al hacer un ECHO en la variable $quest durante el bucle, el resultado es el esperado", ¿por qué no haces echo de dicha variable en tu html? ¿De qué haces echo que te da un resultado final erróneo?

Comment: Todos los reemplazos ocurren dentro de la variable $articulo. Esa es la variable que se imprime al final, ya con los enlaces, puesto que está variable tiene todo el texto del artículo. visita http://exegesis-biblica.com/g-nesis-cap-tulo-1.html para que tengas una mejor idea de lo que estamos hablando.

Comment: Creo que es más bien un error de organización de tu código. Dentro del foreach puedes perfectamente organizar tu cadena sin necesidad de recurrir al str_replace... concatenando el texto e imprimiendo al salir del bucle. De todos modos, si quieres hacerlo como lo tienes planteado, revisa lo que hay en $book, porque no te está aceptando las enteros de dos dígitos.

Comment: $book si acepta los enteros de dos dígitos, por eso aparecen los versículos completos en el array $enlace al imprimir con print_r($enlace). ¿Me puedes dar un ejemplo de como organizar la cadena dentro del foreach?

Comment: Bueno, tuve que irme a Misa :) Visitando la página veo que al parecer lo solucionaste, si es así edita la respuesta o crea una pregunta con la solución para que pueda servir a otros en un futuro. Si no lo has solucionado te sugiero que muestres tu código completo, pues por fracciones es difícil tener una idea general de lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: @RicardoMaldonado lo que publicaste en la pregunta como solución, debería ir publicado **como respuesta**.¿Podrías eliminarlo e ahí y publicarlo correctamente?

Answer (score 1):

> Solución agregada por el OP en la [revisión 4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/50262/4), la cual posteriormente fue mejorada.

Ya lo solucioné...

Lo que hice fue lo siguiente:

1. Recorrí el array a la inversa con el método mencionado previamente
2. Reemplace los enlaces con una secuencia unica
3. Reemplace la secuencia con el texto original y el enlace

Lo que pasaba es que el código consideraba que Genesis 1:3 y Genesis 1:30 eran lo mismo, y se cortaba al llegar a 3, con una secuencia única se pueden diferenciar los versículos.

No sé si me explique bien, pero así fue como lo solucioné